# Java Native Interface: data type of long integers

Tags: java, c, cryptography, java-native-interface, gmp

I am working on a Cryptographic project, where several 1024 bit numbers (using [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) in C) are generated. These numbers are communicated via a Java program (the C file is called through JNI). I need those large numbers to be returned to the Java program. Now, data types are different `mpz_t` and [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), so which *[native](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html)* data type should be used?

Comment: Sounds like you should convert your mpz_t value into a string, then into a jstring, and pass that result to the BigInteger constructor.  Is that was you were asking?

Comment: @Samhain That may be one way to solve this! Thank you.

Comment: Another approach is through byte arrays if GMP supports that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C part.

```
#include <jni.h>

jbyteArray array(mpz_t *m) {
  const size_t size = sizeof (mpz_t);
  jbyteArray jbytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, (jsize) size);
  if (result != NULL) {
    jbyte *cbytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, result, NULL);
    if (cbytes != NULL) {
      int i;
      for (i = (int) (size - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        cbytes[i] = (jbyte) (*m & 0xFF);
        *m >>= 8;
      }
      (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, result, cbytes, 0);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Test_bytes(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls) {
  mpz_t *m = getSome();
  return array(m);
}
```

Java part.

```
static native byte[] bytes();

static BigInteger bigInteger() {
    final byte[] bytes = bytes();
    return bytes == null ? null : new BigInteger(1, bytes);
}
```

Note that the first argument `1` means a positive `signum`.

Answer (score 2):

`jbyteArray` because `BigInteger` can be serialized and deserialized to/from Java `byte[]` and `mpz_t` can be serialized and deserialized to/from a structure that—without the header—seems like it would be same sequences of bytes.